# Control events of Object (HTML) by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

Is it possible to control an object that contains a swf that streams music, I want to be able to pause it by JS, but I don't know if that's possible or not.

e.g.

```
<embed src="http://www.example.com/mp3player.swf" quality="high" width="0" height="0" name="main" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

To be able to pause it by something similar (pseudo code):

```
function pauseVideo()
{
    // pause the video
}
```

by this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="pauseVideo()" value="pause" />
```

Also other events such as continue, stop, etc...

The streaming works fine, but it's just how to control the events I do not know how to.

Answer (score 1):

this kind of function does not work natively with JavaScript. The Player can however provide functions that can be called by JavaScript.

You must ask whoever made the player `mp3player.swf` to provide them.